Are there vagrant boxes for recent Ubuntu releases?
In the past there have been vagrantboxes provided for each Ubuntu release, for example:

https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64
https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/jammy64
https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/mantic64

However I can't see a box for Noble Numbat. The latter two boxes do still seem to be being kept up to date, so it seems like vagrant boxes are still supported at least somewhat.
Looking at the release directories (e.g: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/mantic/current/) I do see the vagrant boxes listed there for previous versions, but again not for Noble.
Is this expected? Are boxes for Noble onwards going to be published?

That would be something only the Ubuntu maker can answer. The volunteers on this site have no such info.

There are no Vagrant boxes published by Ubuntu for the 24.04 (Noble Numbat). From the Ubuntu 24.04 release notes:

Starting in Ubuntu 24.04, Canonical no longer produces Vagrant images. This is due upstream Debian questions of maintainership and Canonical dropping vagrant from the Ubuntu archives.

Source: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-release-notes/39890 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/2065126
There might be boxes for Noble from other publishers that can be found in Vagrant Cloud. It's also possible to create one yourself, as it's described in the release notes linked above.
It also seems that the boxes for the previous versions of Ubuntu are still getting updated, so you could use the box of a previous LTS (ex. Jammy), if using the latest version is not required for your use-case.

I created a noble64 box by do-release-upgrade from ubuntu/jammy64
https://portal.cloud.hashicorp.com/vagrant/discover/phz/noble64
Build pipeline is available at https://github.com/phzfi/noble64
